# How to create firehose stream and check if it's been created?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need to create an AWS firehose stream, so I made the following code:

```
def create_kinesis_firehose_stream(firehoseStreamName, roleARN, bucketARN, prefix, sizeInMBs, intervalInSeconds):
    createdFirehose = None

    try:
        createdFirehose = firehoseAWS.create_delivery_stream(
            DeliveryStreamName = firehoseStreamName,
            S3DestinationConfiguration = {
                'RoleARN': roleARN,
                'BucketARN': bucketARN,
                'Prefix': prefix,
                'BufferingHints': {
                    'SizeInMBs': sizeInMBs,
                    'IntervalInSeconds': intervalInSeconds
                }
            })
    except Exception as E:
        print (E)
        return {'isValid': False }

    httpStatusCode = createdFirehose['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
    if httpStatusCode != 200:
        raise Exception('firehoseAWS.create_delivery_stream function returned http code: ' + httpStatusCode)
        return {'isValid': False}

    firehoseStatus = None
    firehoseOnCreationResponse = None
    while firehoseStatus != 'ACTIVE':
        time.sleep(5) **** is this the proper way ? ****
        try:
            firehoseOnCreationResponse = firehoseAWS.describe_delivery_stream(DeliveryStreamName = firehoseStreamName)

            if firehoseOnCreationResponse['DeliveryStreamDescription'] != None:
                if firehoseOnCreationResponse['DeliveryStreamDescription']['DeliveryStreamStatus'] != None:
                    firehoseStatus = firehoseOnCreationResponse['DeliveryStreamDescription']['DeliveryStreamStatus']
                    print ('Waiting for the new ' + firehoseStreamName + ' Firehose to be created.')
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
            return {'isValid': False}

    # Log:
    print('Succeed to create new Kinesis Firehose Stream, Stream Name: ' + firehoseStreamName)
    return { 'isValid': firehoseOnCreationResponse['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200 }
```

What I done in this function is to create the firehose, and then, I used `describe_delivery_stream` function to retrieve the firehose which I created, to see if it's actually created.

What's going on is like this, when the `create_delivery_stream` is being called, it takes about a minute to create the firehose stream and move it to 'ACTIVE' status, so I added a sleep of 5 seconds to call the `describe_delivery_stream` until the firehose is created properly.

It seems like the `sleep` can damage my code and not well formed in this case.

I need to know if there is an another way to check if my firehose created properly ?

Comment: Why does `sleep` damage your code?

Comment: @MattHouser it's not appropriate to use it while I got few more functions ahead, and also it could stuck there and won't stop, I also thought about adding a maximum value of tries which could tell me if it succeed or not, but still, I don't think it the best practice for this issue.

Comment: Well, it depends on what your program is doing and how it's structured. In many cases, using `sleep` to wait for some time is a 100% valid thing to do. To avoid an infinite loop, you can add a counter that aborts after `n` iterations. Also, depending on your application, you could add a "cancel" check. But don't think that `sleep` is simply bad. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @MattHouser Ok, but is there some another approach for dealing this issue ? My purpose is to check that this firehose is actually created